# How to create conditional objects in Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am receiving a fairly flat set of data that has homePhone, cellPhone and workPhone on it.  The destination expects the data to be normalized so that it gets:

```
{
...
 "phones": [
   {"type":"work", "number":"888-888-888"},
   {"type":"cell", "number":"888-888-888"},
   {"type":"home", "number":"888-888-888"},
 ]
...
}
```

If one of the fields is null or blank then that element should not be sent.  How can I configure the body of an HTTP post action to optionally add an object to the array only if the incoming property has a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer, it's the Compose action with the Append to array variable action.  It allows the composition of objects and then the Append to array allows the build up of the objects in an array.

[image: Compose]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a **condition statement** to control workflow action like the sample in the screenshot.

[image]

For more details, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement).